# Sqoop Not able to detect updates when no lastmodified date

Tags: sqoop, sqoop2

I have Orders Mysql Table which have auto incremet id  and order status will get updated and don't have any last modified date and It is very big table.Now I planned to create real time sink  to HDFS using Sqoop.

I am not able to capture updates in sqoop.
I tried both append and merge key option with lastmodified but both not able to solve problem.

I can't reload entire table since it is very huge.

I am looking for a way using sqoop how we can detect updates like status changes and move to hdfs

Comment: Can you provide the sqoop command you are trying with. In append mode, sqoop will import only the new rows that are continuously being added with increasing row id values. It can not import the updates to existing rows.

Comment: This will take changes(updates) based on last modified date  and merge with existing data based on id in sqoop 
sqoop job --create oms_download_details -- import   --connect jdbc:mysql://<yourIp>/<dbname>?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull  --username <username> \
--password <password> --table <tablename>  --target-dir <target Directory> --incremental  \
lastmodified --merge-key id --check-column last_modified_time --fields-terminated-by ',' --last-value '2016-01-01 00:00:00'  -m 1 \
--driver 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' --optionally-enclosed-by '\"';

Comment: But My question is if there is no date column how sqoop can do the same

Comment: you don't have any date column which can indicate you that row is being inserted or updated???

Comment: Yes I don't have any date column as well as no history table only ststus will get updated